# How do I test light wiring that has been exposed to the elements?

Tags: light-fixture

I have a light on the side of my house that has not had a light fixture on it for many years. I forget that it is there most of the time. The wires have the caps on them but what is the likelihood that I can just buy a light and attach it without any issues? It is under an overhang but I am worried that it has been exposed for too long. I found what I think are voltage testers in my late Dad's toolbox...two black wires with metal probes on the ends with different levels of voltage written on the one end (120-480) that probably light up and the other one has one red wire and one black wire with the metal probes and a light bulb on the other end (it says AC/DC 80-500V). Where I touch which wire to where would be appreciated. I wasn't able to figure out how to include images. Thanks.

Comment: Turn off the breaker for the light(if known) or the main breaker.  Feel the insulation on the wires.  If soft, bendable, and does not fall off or break, then it is probably still good.  I would get a new multi meter(not expensive) and if insulation is good, then you should get ~120 volts between hot(black) and neutral(white) with the beaker on.

Comment: When the breaker is off, unscrew the wire nuts ("caps") and take a look at the bare copper. If it's bright & shiny, you're in good shape, if it's dull and grey/black, then you might need a bit of emery cloth to clean it up until it's bright and shiny and can make good electrical contact again. At a minimum, you should buy an outdoor cover with a gasket for the box that these wires stick out of and put that on there if you decide to not use them for a light.

Comment: The insulation on the wires is cracking and looks brittle.

Comment: Bad insulation leads to shorts/fires.  You need to replace the wires/cable to where the insulation is good.  Depending where it goes a simple splice inside the wall with an accessible junction box might be enough or need to go all the way to the switch.